# Send encrypted AND signed mail with .NET MailMessage in c#

Tags: c#, certificate, signing, mailmessage

I want to send an encrypted and signed mail without using any third-party library.
I'm able to send an email signed or encrypted. But both is not working.
I've tried to send a mail with Thunderbird and looked at the source, but theres nothing that tells the mail is encrypted and signed.
When I use following code

```
byte[] bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("TestBody");
SignedCms cms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(bodyBytes), false);
CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, signerCert); //X509Certificate2 with private key of sender
cms.ComputeSignature(signer);
byte[] signedBytes = cms.Encode();
EnvelopedCms ecms = new EnvelopedCms(new ContentInfo(signedBytes));
CmsRecipient cmsr = new CmsRecipient(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, encryptCert); //X509Certificate2 with public key of recipient
ecms.Encrypt(cmsr);
byte[] encryptedBytes = ecms.Encode();
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
msg.From = new MailAddress(from);
msg.Subject = subject;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encryptedBytes);
AlternateView av = new AlternateView(ms, "application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data;name=smime.p7m");
msg.AlternateViews.Add(av);
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("[smtpServer]", 25);
smtp.Send(msg);
```

the MailClient just decrypts or checks the signature of the message.. the action which i perform last. How can I tell the Client to do both, decryption and signature check?

Comment: did you ever succeed?